# How to handle a long press event with yii2fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, yii2, fullcalendar

I use [yii2fullcalendar](https://github.com/philippfrenzel/yii2fullcalendar) for my website.

On mobile device, a "dayClick" event is fired although we just want to scroll down the screen.

How to change "dayClick" to a day double click event ?

**UPDATE:**
Actually, I want to avoid an inconvenient usage on mobile device. So, it's better if we can set a "long press" parameter instead of finding the way to change "dayClick" to a day double click event.

This is my view.php

```
<?= \yii2fullcalendar\yii2fullcalendar::widget(array(
        'options' => [
        ],
        'clientOptions' => [
            'allDaySlot' => false,
            'selectHelper' => true,
            'eventClick' => new JsExpression($JSEventClick),
            'dayClick' => new JsExpression($JSDayClick),
            'eventMouseover' =>new JsExpression($JSDayMouseover),
            'eventMouseout' =>new JsExpression($JSDayMouseout),
            'defaultView' => 'agendaWeek',
            'firstDay' => date('w'),  // Sunday=0, Monday=1, Tuesday=2, etc.
            'header' => [
                'center'=>'prev,next today',
                'left'=>'',
                'right'=>'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month',
            ],
        ],
        'ajaxEvents' => Url::to(......)
    ));
    ?>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a better solution for my issue.

That is set a parameter to:

```
longPressDelay
```

within the client options as below

```
<?= \yii2fullcalendar\yii2fullcalendar::widget(array(
        'options' => [
        ],
        'clientOptions' => [
            'allDaySlot' => false,
            'selectHelper' => true,
            'eventClick' => new JsExpression($JSEventClick),
            'dayClick' => new JsExpression($JSDayClick),
            'eventMouseover' =>new JsExpression($JSDayMouseover),
            'eventMouseout' =>new JsExpression($JSDayMouseout),
            'defaultView' => 'agendaWeek',

            'longPressDelay' => 1500, // -> Add here

            'firstDay' => date('w'),  // Sunday=0, Monday=1, Tuesday=2, etc.
            'header' => [
                'center'=>'prev,next today',
                'left'=>'',
                'right'=>'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month',
            ],
        ],
        'ajaxEvents' => Url::to(......)
    ));
    ?>
```

Refer to:
https://github.com/philippfrenzel/yii2fullcalendar/issues/72#issuecomment-268556312

Comment: While I agree that's a better solution, could you modify your question appropriately? What you're recommending is not how to handle a double-tap but how to handle a long press. That way future viewers can be directed to what they need.

Comment: Yes, I modified question.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to modify your dayClick function to handle a double click using the following algorithm:

- Set variable `clicked_once` to false.
- On click:

  - If !clicked_once

    - Set `clicked_once` to true.
    - Start a timeout function to occur after xx seconds.

      - On timeout, set clicked_once to false.
  - If clicked_once

    - Perform event
    - set `clicked_once` to false.

Sorry to provide an algorithm rather than code, don't have any reference material in front of me at them moment.